# How can I put tabs in text files from Terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal

When I use Terminal to find every job that has been worked on last twenty-four hours I get a text file with lines like this:

ABC 12345 Job Worked on DATE

DEF 67890 Another Job on DATE

GHI 10112 Final Job on DATE

This text file can be up to hundred lines. I have to insert all this data into a tabel in Microsoft Excel. To make my life easier I would like to figure out how to add a tab in every line, after the numbers.

Something like this:

```
echo "ABC 12345 <tab> Job Worked on DATE" >> jobs.txt
echo "DEF 67890 <tab> Another Job on DATE" >> jobs.txt
echo "GHI 10112 <tab> Final Job on DATE" >> jobs.txt
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You probably don't want spaces surrounding the tab characters.

Comment: It does not need to be a tab character, in MS excel you can choose the separator character for import, you can choose something that is visible like ',' or ';' and just edit the file with those characters in.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use echo -e with \t for a tab. Like this:

```
echo -e "ABC 12345 \t Job Worked on DATE" >> jobs.txt
```

Comment: What does the -e flag do? When I man echo, it only gives me a -n flag.

Comment: @W3Geek: It depends on which version of `echo` you're using. bash's built-in `echo` command recognizes `-e`, which enables interpretation of certain backslash-escaped characters, including `\t` for tab. But not all versions of `echo` do this. The `printf` command is a better alternative -- but given that you already have the information as text, it's even better to transform it using `sed`, `awk`, or something similar.

Comment: Okay I see how -e flag works. =) It didn't show up in my 'man echo' however. I don't understand what the sed or awk commands do.

Comment: The key is the "-e" option, one time I forgot this option and get '\t' in the text

Answer (score 6):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to type a raw Tab.

---

You can also use `$'...'` c-string syntax:

```
echo $'ABC 12345 \t Job Worked on DATE' >> jobs.txt
```

Comment: Yes, but since the OP has all the data as text, and just needs to transform it, re-typing it would *not* be the best approach.

Comment: You are right @KeithThompson. This would not be the best approach for what I'm doing. I chose the post above because his was the most simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Append a tab to the second field:

```
awk '{$2 = $2 "\t"; print}' inputfile  > outputfile
```

Similar, but using a regex:

```
sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+/&\t/' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: What does the 'awk' and 'sed' commands do?

Comment: @W3Geek: They're both text-transformation filters. `awk` in particular is a full-blown programming language (and `sed` arguably is as well). It's impossible to explain them fully in a comment. Try `man sed` and/or `man awk` if your system has the `man` command, or do a Google or Wikipedia search.

Comment: That `sed` command doesn't work, at least not for me (GNU sed 4.2.1). `sed` doesn't recognize extended regular expressions (specifically the `+` qualifier) by default. And if it did, your `s///` command would *replace* a sequence of digits by a tab character; you want to *add* a tab character.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I've fixed both problems.

Comment: @W3Geek: Can you be more specific with your question? Both commands do the same thing which is to put a tab after the number.

Comment: I understand what regular expressions are and I understand how to use them. I have been reading up on these commands to see how they work. It looks like both of them are very powerful.